# Export powershell script to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a small script which retrieves the LastLogonTimestamp and the SAMAccount for all users in a particular OU in AD and converts the timestamp to a date and extracts just the date from the string. That part works fine. I then would like to output that to a CSV so it may be opened in Excel and be perfectly formated into columns and look all pretty.

I have tried ConvertTo-Csv and Export-Csv but have been uncuccessful. The problem is I am new to Powershell. This is my first script and I don't fully understand how this works. My script is probably terribly messy and illogical but it does the job so far.

Please help. Thanks.

```
$userlist = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=IT,DC=whatever,DC=com,DC=au" -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,LastLogonTimestamp,SAMAccountName | Sort-Object -Property Name

$userlist | ForEach-Object {
    $last = $_.LastLogonTimestamp;
    $ADName = $_.SAMAccountName;

    $tstamp = w32tm /ntte $last;
    if($tstamp.Length -lt "40"){}else
    {
        $ADDate = [DateTime]::Parse($tstamp.Split('-')[1]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        write-host $ADDate;
        write-host $ADName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create objects for each user and pipe those to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet:

```
$usersList | %{

# current logic

$user = new-object psobject
$user | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name LastLogon -value $last
$user | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name ADName -value $ADName
$user | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name ADDate -value $ADDate
$user
} | export-csv test.csv -notype
```

Alternative syntax for populating the object:

```
$properties = @{"LastLogon" = $last; "ADName" = $ADName; "ADDate" = $ADDate}
$user = new-object psobject -property $properties
```

Comment: I've unvolontary downvoted your answer... probably because I was reading it with a smartphone and touched it. Can you edit it, so I can re-upvote it??

Comment: @Christian - Ah, I have done that :) Anyway, added the alternative syntax for creating objects.